# "Exception has been thrown by target of an invocation" for /findMeetingTimes request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am developing a multi-tenant application with the Microsoft Graph API that makes use of the `/findMeetingTimes` endpoint. After many months of successful requests, on January 15th I started to see some errors coming through for a specific kind of request for some users.

The failing request is a `POST` to `/findMeetingTimes` for a single attendee who is the user on who's behalf I'm making the request. The same requests for more than a single attendee are still completing just fine, even if the user who authorized the request is included.

Nothing has changed in my request so this seems like it's either a change on the API side or a change in the user's configuration that's broken their ability to make requests of this type. Any insight on this error in this context would be helpful!

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes
```

Request body:

```
{
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "[email of user who authorized the request]"
      },
      "type": "Required"
    }
  ],
  "meetingDuration": "PT30M",
  "minimumAttendeePercentage": 100,
  "maxCandidates": 400,
  "timeConstraint": {
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": [DateTime],
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": [DateTime],
          "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
      }
    ],
    "activityDomain": "Unrestricted"
  }
}
```

Returns (one specific example):

```
500: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an 
invocation.", "innerError":{"request-id":"a039234e-f64e-489a-96cf
ff4f686a4389","date":"2018-01-18T01:51:49"}
```

Comment: Is this still happening? I cannot reproduce it so it might be limited to certain users.

Comment: @JasonJohnston yes -- this is still happening but only for certain users. (I have two users at different companies who are running into this error, while other users on their tenants are not seeing these errors). Is there any info I can give you that would be helpful for debugging? I included a request-id above but I have plenty more.

Comment: It would be helpful to get the full set of response headers from an error. If you prefer to share that privately you can ping me on Twitter @JasonJohMSFT